# How can I bind to multiple values in vue.js for a custom multiselect checkbox group?

Tags: vue.js

I know [how to](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#select) bind a Vue application to a `select` with `multiple` attribute.

But in this particular case, I have a list of checkboxes that can be turned on or off. They are attributes of a residency to reserve.

For example, user sees a list of features of an accommodation like :

[image]

How can I bind these?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) library.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  data: {
    value: [],
    accommodation: [{
        feature: 'Party'
      },
      {
        feature: 'Food'
      },
      {
        feature: 'Oven'
      },
      {
        feature: 'AC'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    customLabel(option) {
      return `${option.feature}`
    },
    isSelected(option) {
      return this.value.some((op) => op.feature === option.feature)
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.2/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.3/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <multiselect v-model="value" :options="accommodation" :multiple="true" track-by="feature"  :custom-label="customLabel" :close-on-select="false">
    <span class="checkbox-label" slot="option" slot-scope="scope">
    {{ scope.option.feature }}
      <input class="test" type="checkbox" :checked="isSelected(scope.option)" @focus.prevent :key="scope.option.feature" />
    </span>
  </multiselect>
</div>
```